# MySQL in Docker mounted directory permissions are messed up on external SSD

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, file-permissions

I'm running MySQL inside a docker image and I'm mounting a directory from the host inside the container to have the database persisted `./db:/var/lib/mysql`.
Since the data got really big, I had to move everything to my external SSD. Now it seems that the permissions of the mounted directory are messed up. When I let MySQL container initialize the `./db` directory, it's all good. But if I stop the containers, remove the external SSD, and connect it back and spin up the containers again, the MySQL container keeps restarting, logging things like:

```
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/._binlog.000004': Operation not permitted
```

- I'm running docker on my mac.
- `ls -l`: `drwxrwxrwx@ 1 amir  staff   131072 May  5 21:25 db`.
- `docker -v`: `Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b`.
- `docker-compose -v`: `docker-compose version 1.25.4, build 8d51620a`
- `docker-compose.yml`:

  ```
  version: "3"

  services:
    db:
      image: mysql
      volumes:
        - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
      restart: always
      ports:
        - "3306:3306"
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      networks:
        - projectnetwork
  networks:
    projectnetwork:
  ```

Any hints to how I can solve this problem would be greatly appreciated :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I'm not sure if this is the best way to solve this, but I can get around the issue with this at the moment. Please let me know if this is totally dumb and there are better solutions.

I tried running the container with `docker` itself and passing `--user "$(id -u):$(id -g)"` and it worked.
Unfortunately, we can't do sub bash commands in `docker-compose` file, so I had to create my own script that sets an environment variable and runs docker-compose:

```
DOCKER_COMPOSE_USER=$(id -u):$(id -g) docker-compose up -d
```

And in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
user: ${DOCKER_COMPOSE_USER}
```

That did the trick!